# SQL: how to write filter for such string - '10xx8xx0xx' (x - any symbol)?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Is it possible at all to write filter for such string: `10xx8xx0xx`, where x - any symbol, but order of "not x" and it's place in the string is important?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very unclear. Makes it hard to tell what you want *exactly*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PostgreSQL you have several wildcards that you can use in [`LIKE` expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/functions-matching.html). An underscore `_` matches a single character:

```
 select * from mytable
 where mystring like '10__8__0__'
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Why did you edit `LIKE` into `similar to` in first query?

Comment: In order to search for an underscore you simply use the `ESCAPE` clause: `LIKE '10\__' ESCAPE '\' ` searches for a string starting wiht `10`, followed by an underscore, followed by a single character.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: If I understand the question right (which is a bit unclear), your **first answer** was correct. The later changes are wrong. You can have multiple `_` in the pattern for a `LIKE` operator, no problem. No escape sequences needed at all. **col ~~ '10__8__0__'**

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter You are right - I re-read the doc, and fixed the answer again. I wish I had an instance of PostgreSQL to try out my first answer - that would have saved me a lot of typing!  Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I propose you **roll back** all your edits since the original. While `similar to` works now, it is inferior to `LIKE` (`~~`) which works just as well in this case and is the much faster operator. `similar to` is a curiosity that is only in PostgreSQL because it is defined in the SQL standard.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks! I love the rollback feature. I'm fairly new around here, so I did not know it existed.

Answer (score 5):

```
select ... where field like '10__8__0__'
```

SQL Like : % for any number of characters, _ for just one.